# #define FILE_APPVENDORPARAM APP_NAME"VENDOR" meaning of this line

Tags: c

I am working on one embedded project based on c language.

Can you explain me following declaration meaning:

```
#define FILE_APPVENDORPARAM         APP_NAME"VENDOR"
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the line you show, there must be another #define that defines `APP_NAME`, for example like this:

```
#define APP_NAME "SomeName"
```

Then this line:

```
#define FILE_APPVENDORPARAM         APP_NAME"VENDOR"
```

defines `FILE_APPVENDORPARAM` as `"SomeName""VENDOR"` which is the same thing as `"SomeNameVENDOR"`

Comment: Thank you sir. Got it